# RESTful design: resolving relationships

Tags: api, rest

My questions are based on this article: [should-restful-apis-include-relationships](http://idbentley.com/blog/2013/03/14/should-restful-apis-include-relationships/)

Let's say I have the following resources: users and roles

A single user can be retrieved by **api/users/{userId}** and a single role by **api/roles/{roleId}**

The response data of a single user looks like this:

```
Id: 1
Firstname: Alice
Lastname: Henderson
Email: alice@henderson.com
Roles: api/users/1/roles
```

To get the roles of this user the application needs to call the returned url **api/users/1/roles**

For displaying 1 user this approach seems to be ok. But if I want to display all users with their corresponding roles the application needs 1 call to **api/users** and x calls to **api/users/x/roles**

How can this design be improved for retrieving multiple users and resolving their role relationships?

Answer (score 1):

You can design your API to accept one or more query parameters which specify the detail level you desire. For instance:

```
GET /api/users/1?expand=role(self, id, name)

{
    "id": 1
    "firstName": "Alice"
    "lastName": "Henderson"
    "email": "alice@henderson.com"
    "roles": [
        {
            "self": "api/roles/4"
            "id": 4
            "name": "Administrator"
        },
        {
            "self": "api/roles/7"
            "id": 7
            "name": "Uberuser"
        }
    ]
}
```